# Decoding Hex when pulling Multilingual Email Data with imaplib in Python

Tags: python, email, hex, decode, imaplib

How do I turn this:

```
With Best Regards, JS Chen*\r\n\r\n=E9=A0=8E=E9=82=A6=E7=A7=91=E6=8A=80=E8=82=A1=E4=BB=BD=E6=9C=89=E9=99=90=E5=\r\n=85=AC=E5=8F=B8/Chipbond Technology
```

to this:

```
With Best Regards, JS Chen*\r\n\r\n頎邦科技股份有限公司/Chipbond Technology
```

using python?

I'm pulling mixed language email data using imaplib and it's giving me this hex code with equal signs in-between whenever there are other language characters

Here is my code:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('****@gmail.com', '*********')

mail.select('Inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None,'(SUBJECT "ULVAC RSH-820")')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()
print('searching...')

for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)' )
    raw_email = data[0][1]
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
    print('decoding..')
    for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8')) 

            if msg.is_multipart():
                print('de-partitioning...')
                for part in msg.walk():
                    ctype = part.get_content_type()
                    cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))
                    if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
                        body = part.get_payload()


            else:
                body = msg.get_payload()
```

Comment: I get this error when I use `message_from_bytes` :

Comment: text = text.decode('ASCII', errors='surrogateescape')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emails have a [*content transfer encoding*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding), specifically, the [Quoted-Printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), which is used to make sure the email data stream is ASCII safe.

Simply tell Python to decode the payload by passing in `decode=True` to the [`Message.get_payload()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html?highlight=get_payload#email.message.Message.get_payload):

```
body_data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
charset = part.get_param("charset", "ASCII")
body = body_data.decode(charset, errors="replace")
```

However, this does mean you'll be given *binary* data, even for text content types and so must explicitly decode the data. `get_payload()` is not that helpful here. It is also part of the legacy API; you want to switch to the newer Unicode-friendly API. Do so by using a policy other than the `compat32` policy (the default) when loading a message:

```
from email import policy

# ...

raw_email = data[0][1]
# you may have to use policy.default instead, depending on the line endings
# convention used.
email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email, policy=policy.SMTP)
```

and further down

```
msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1], policy=policy.SMTP)
```

Note that I don't decode the `bytes` value first, by using `email.message_from_bytes()` instead of `email.message_from_string()` you delegate decoding the data to the `email` parser.

Now `email_message` is a [`email.message.EmailMessage` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) instead of the older [`email.message.Message()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html), and you can use the [`EmailMessage.get_content()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content), which for text mime types will return a Unicode text string:

```
body = part.get_content()
```

Comment: Here's what I'm getting: `in _new_message
    msg = self._factory()
TypeError: 'EmailPolicy' object is not callable`

Comment: @Adam sorry; I wrote the answer off the cuff as you didn’t provide a concrete example to quickly test with. I’ve fixed the calls now, the policy needs to be passed in as a keyword argument.

Comment: Bellissimo! Thank you very much, this saved me a ton of work. Have a wonderful day Martijn!